# how to get progress of minicom's kermit file transfer

Tags: linux, serial-port, embedded-linux, kermit

Is there any way to get the progress of file transfer over kermit protocol serially on minicom, as Tera Term gives in windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `gkermit v1.0-5` and above (used with `minicom`),
already has a **"twirling baton"** to show activity/progress during a file transfer.

In case you are stuck with an older version of `gkermit` for some reason,
you can apply this [patch](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=266953) and rebuild gkermit.

---

Be default in minicom, 
hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> to open minicom settings window.
Select `File Transfer Protocols` and configure the kermit tool to use.

> Checkout the minicom kermit settings in this [**mail-thread**](http://lists.denx.de/pipermail/u-boot/2003-June/001527.html).

Next to transfer a file in minicom, hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> and select `kermit` and follow the onscreen instructions to select and transfer a file.

[image: minicom kermit file transfer screen]

Comment: I had installed gkermit, but not getting how can i use it with minicom. TAI